# Eclipse -- hook based on exit code?

Tags: eclipse, system, exit

A question similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496803/is-it-possible-to-customize-install4j-launcher-to-restart-application-process-ba), just for Eclipse.

Is it possible to define hooks which act based on the exit code of the program run within Eclipse? (E.g., restart the program if a specific exit code is observed).

Comment: What do you mean by 'run within Eclipse'? Are you talking about Java programs started from the 'Run' menu?

Comment: @greg-449 for example yes

Comment: For a Java program started from the launch manager you would have to write an Eclipse plug-in and use a debug events listener.

Comment: @greg-449 so tehre is no out-of-the-box solution? Could you write that up as an answer, so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For programs launched using the Eclipse launch manager (for example from the Run menu) the only way to follow their progress is to write an Eclipse plugin which uses a debug events listener to listen to the launch progress.